# How do you pass variables from an Angular controller to a html <script></script>?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linkedin-api

I have variables in my angular controller and I'd like to take the data in the variable and put in a script tag in my html but I have no clue how to execute this.  I'm doing this because I want to take a picture and put it into my LinkedIn post with the share button. Based on the docs [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#methods), it seems pretty straight forward if I can just get the data from my controller into their script tags.

For example:

**controller.js**

```
.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
     $scope.test = "something";
     $scope.hope = 5
     $scope.array = [things];
}
```

**html**

```
<script>
var payload = {
  "comment": $scope.test "content": {
    "title": $scope.hope,
    "someArray": $scope.array,
    "submitted-url": window.location.href
  }
};
</script>
```

//////////////////////////
Thanks for the copious comments. Here is what I'm trying in more detail with LinkedIn:

```
<script type="IN/Share" data-url={{webAddress}} data-counter="right">
                  $.get( "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites", function( response ) {
                    var post = _.first(_.filter(response.posts, function(n){return n.title.replace(/ /g,"-").replace(/[:]/g, "").toLowerCase() === $stateParams.id}));
                    var post1 = _.assign(post, {category: _.first(_.keys(post.categories)), pic: _.first(_.values(post.attachments)).URL, credit: _.first(_.values(post.attachments)).caption, linkCredit: _.first(_.values(post.attachments)).alt, fullStory: post.content.replace(/<(?!\s*\/?\s*p\b)[^>]*>/gi,'')});
                    **var image = post1.pic;**
                    **var title = post1.title;**
                    **var webAddress = window.location.href;**

                    function onLinkedInLoad() {
                      IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", shareContent);
                    }

                   function onSuccess(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                   }

                   function onError(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                   }

                   function shareContent(title, image, webAddress) {

                    var payload = {                         
                      "content": {
                        "title": title,
                        "submitted-image-url": image,
                        "submitted-url": webAddress
                      }
                    };

                    IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
                      .method("POST")
                      .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
                      .result(onSuccess)
                      .error(onError);
                   }
                  });

                  </script>
```

I still think something is going wrong. But what? Am I using the http correctly as I've only done it using Angular thus far.

Comment: You can't do it this way. The script tag gets evaluated well before the controller would ever be initialized. What is the use case for this? Why can't you do whatever you need to do within angular context?

Comment: @charlietfi I have all of the elements in the scope in the html as per normal Angular practice.  I need to also populate the LInkedIn payload parameters with that data.  I don't know how to get the data from angular (where I know how to source it originally) to the script tags.

Comment: Where does the actual data come from? And how?

Comment: @rashadb Then wrap the LinkedIn payload in an angular component of some sort and allow it to drive the data management.  This is not the correct way to handle it.

Comment: @charlietfi - I know I can't do it this way but I don't know how to handle it at all, thus the reason I'm here.

Comment: @David, I need a little more guidance than that in regard to how I wrap it in Angular but could still send it out as part of LinkedIn. Thanks!

Comment: Again..where does the data come from? And why can't you initialize the linkedIn code inside angular when you get that data?

Comment: @charlietfi the data comes from an angular $http.get call.

Comment: So just initialize whatever linkedIn code you need to inside the $http callback

Comment: @charlietfi - is this the right track? I updated the question with what I tried as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the snippet just below how to access Angular Scope outside angular :)

**EDIT (Afer reading your updated question)**

You'll better transcode all your `LinkedIn` scripts to angular way as kicken suggest you :) :

1. less spagetti code
2. less maintenance
3. **more time to watch lol cats on YT** !

If you still want to do that way :) ==>

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'toto';
  $scope.hope = 'My Title';
  $scope.array = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  $scope.payload = {};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myFunction = function() {

      var e = document.getElementById('app');     
      var $scope = angular.element(e).scope();
      console.log($scope.payload);
      $scope.payload = {
        "comment": $scope.test,
        "content": {
          "title": $scope.hope,
          "someArray": $scope.array,
          "submitted-url": window.location.href
         }
      };
      $scope.$apply();
    };
</script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl" id="app">
  <p>Hello {{payload}}!</p>
  <button onclick="javascript:myFunction()">Click me</button>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try and pass data from Angular into a generic `<script>` tag, what you need to do is move the LinkedIn code into Angular.

A quick glance at [the JavascriptSDK documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#methods) suggests that this is the key code for making the linked in request:

```
IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
  .method("POST")
  .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
  .result(onSuccess)
  .error(onError);
```

What you can do then is place that code into your angular code at whatever point you need it.  You mention the data for your payload comes from a $http request so you would likely want this into your $http success handler.

```
$http({url:'/whatever'}).then(function(response){
    var payload = { /* Generate payload */ };

    IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
      .method("POST")
      .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
      .result(onSuccess)
      .error(onError);

    function onSuccess(){ /* LinkedIn success */ }
    function onError(){ /* LinkedIn error */ }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, moving all of your javascript code into your controller would be the best solution if possible. To do that, your controller would look something like this:

```
.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
  $scope.test = "something";
  $scope.hope = 5
  $scope.array = [things];


  $scope.sendData = function () {
    var data = $.param({
      "comment": $scope.test,
      "content": {
      "title": $scope.hope,
      "someArray": $scope.array,
      "submitted-url": window.location.href
    });

    var config = {
      headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
      }
    }

    $http.post('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json', data, config)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //it worked
      })
      .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        //there was an error
    });
  };    
}
```

Then, in your html, you would put ng-submit="sendData()" on the form you use to share. If the share stuff isn't in a form, you could then just do ng-click="sendData()".

Comment: I see that but from what I see I still don't know how that works with the plugin; it's not sending the data with it.